# Using locust with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, locust

I am trying to run locust using pytest. I have created this python file but it is not showing any output. pytest doesnot collect the test. How can I use locust with pytest

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task
class WebsiteTasks(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.index()

    @task(2)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def about(self):
        self.client.get("/page/about")


class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    task = WebsiteTasks
    host = "localhost:5000"
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 5000
```

When I run pytest locust_test.py this is the output:

```
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/user/Desktop/testing
collected 0 items
```

Comment: If you want to drive locust load test using pytest, my recommendation would be not to do that at all. pytest is for short living test. locust is for load testing. They won't play nice together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pytest only sees and runs tests that are named a certain way (both class and function must start with "test").

What you'll want to do is write a test that then uses [Locust as a library](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/use-as-lib.html) to programmatically start your Locust test.

```
import gevent
from locustfile import WebsiteUser
from locust.env import Environment
from locust.stats import stats_printer, stats_history


def test_locust():
    # setup Environment and Runner
    env = Environment(user_classes=[WebsiteUser])
    env.create_local_runner()

    # start a greenlet that periodically outputs the current stats
    gevent.spawn(stats_printer(env.stats))

    # start a greenlet that save current stats to history
    gevent.spawn(stats_history, env.runner)

    # start the test
    env.runner.start(1, spawn_rate=10)

    # in 60 seconds stop the runner
    gevent.spawn_later(60, lambda: env.runner.quit())

    # wait for the greenlets
    env.runner.greenlet.join()
```

You can write test assertions based on your pass/fail criteria before you quit the runner. Perhaps write a different function for the lambda to call that checks `env.stats` for failures and response times first and then calls `env.runner.quit()` quit.